# Eliminating null values in union

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, sql-null

I'm doing a query across databases with an identical structure, to show a mapping from a source value to a target value.
Every one of my databases has a table with two columns: **source** and **target**

**DB1**

| Source | Target |
| --- | --- |
| A | X |
| A | Y |
| B | NULL |
| C | NULL |

**DB2**

| Source | Target |
| --- | --- |
| A | NULL |
| A | Y |
| B | Z |

So my query is

```
Select t.Source, t.Target
from DB1.table t
union
Select t.Source, t.Target
from DB2.table t
```

What I'm getting is

| Source | Target |
| --- | --- |
| A | X |
| A | Y |
| **B** | **NULL** |
| C | NULL |
| B | Z |
| **A** | **NULL** |

But I'm only interested in the target being NULL, if there is no other mapping present.
So I'm looking for the following result:

| Source | Target |
| --- | --- |
| A | X |
| A | Y |
| C | NULL |
| B | Z |

How can I easily eliminate the highlighted rows `A | NULL` and `B | NULL` from my results?

I've seen a few answers suggesting using `MAX(Target)`, but that won't work for me since I can have multiple valid mappings for a single source (`A | X` and  `A | Y`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would work, just give a number based on NULL, and select the first:

```
SELECT  TOP(1) WITH TIES UN.Source
,       UN.Target
FROM    (
            Select t.Source, t.Target
            from DB1.table t
            union
            Select t.Source, t.Target
            from DB2.table t
        ) AS UN
ORDER BY DENSE_RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY UN.Source ORDER BY CASE WHEN UN.Target IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and report back. Never heard of  `WITH TIES` or `DENSE_RANK` before :)

Comment: Personally I would avoid the `WITH TIES` and just do a `SELECT` where dense rank is 1. It will add a completely unnecessary sort operation for something that can be done with a simple filter.

Comment: @MartinSmith, good point. I like the readability of the `WITH TIES` method, though that is personal of course. And if performance isn't troublesome I prefer readability to micro-tuning.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks. @MartinSmith, I ended up following your advice, avoiding the order by.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to think in terms of minimums:

```
with data as (
    select Source, Target from DB1.<table> union
    select Source, Target from DB2.<table>
), qualified as (
    select *,
        case when Target is not null or min(Target) over (partition by Source) is null
             then 1 end as Keep
    from data
)
select Source, Target from qualified where Keep = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's the solution I went with, based on the answer of @HoneyBadger, including the suggestion made by @MartinSmith in the comments

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT  UN.Source
    ,       UN.Target
    ,       DENSE_RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY UN.Source ORDER BY CASE WHEN UN.Target IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) as ranking
    FROM    (
                Select t.Source, t.Target
                from DB1.table t
                union
                Select t.Source, t.Target
                from DB2.table t
            ) AS UN
    ) UN2
WHERE UN2.ranking = 1
ORDER BY UN2.Source, UN2.Target
```

This solution selects only the records that have a `DENSE_RANK` of 1, avoiding  the `TOP(1) WITH TIES`.